# Server 2008 bombards network, causing slow speed

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008

My Windows Server 2008 after a new install seems to bombard the network causing slow data transmissions between itself and any other device.
However file transfer between any other devices is fine.

Therefore the file transfer between a PC and the server is under 100kb/s compared to 56MB/s with other devices.

Since the server is also broadcasting the internet through ICS, it also makes this unbearably slow.

The activity light on the switch is going crazy when idleing, compared to those of other computers.

Within wireshark, there are a lot of the following in back and red:
"TCP segment of a reassembled PDU", source server, destination desktop (reports hedder checksum incorrect)
"TCP out-of-order, TCP segment of a reassembled PDU", source server, destination desktop (reports hedder checksum incorrect)

I have already tried the following:

- new drivers
- direct connection using x-over cable
- different ports on the switch (TP-Link SG2109WEB)
- disable ICS

It is literally just a case of as soon as the server has booted and it active on the network that immediately it starts to slow down.
If as soon as it becomes availible, file transfer will be high speed, but will immediately start to slow down, and then after two minutes maximum they are back down at 100kb/s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out in the end it was a faulty PCI card.
Card was exchanged and the issue disappeared

Answer (score 0):

If the server's network interface is failing, it could cause a lot of repeat traffic. A quick check is to use something like `ping -n 100 -l 512 servername` and see if there is any packet loss.

Many problems can cause packet loss but it will help identify what is happening.

Comment: interesting, tried that, ran it 5 times, no packet loss whatsoever.
However, after running that 5 times, file transfer speeds increased from 318kb/s before to 7.12MB/s after.
But it alreadys has started to decrease again...... :(

Comment: Do you have antivirus or firewall on server? maybe disable them and see if that might cause the issue. you can also try to bypass the switch or test with another switch.

Comment: I've also tried an unmanaged switch, and crossover between the server and different PC's - the server keeps doing the same.
All the computers and the server are running sophos, and disabling it does nothing